Suppressing printing of "n.d." on certain items in authordate style in BibLaTeX
I'm trying to disable the printing of "n.d." in citations and in the bibliography entries of certain items in my bibliography that lack dates, but for some reason it is not working:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \AtEveryBibitem{%
      \ifkeyword{nodate}{%
       \clearfield{year}%
       \clearfield{date}%
}{}}


\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}

@book {dated,
title   = {Dated Work},
date    = {1972},
}

@book {undated,
title       = {Undated Work},
keywords    = {nodate},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}



\begin{document}

Citation of dated item.\footcite{dated} Citation of undated item.\footcite{undated}

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}



Are there any entries for which you do want "no date"? It's pretty easy to disable the feature completely, but having it for some and not for other entries is probably more tricky.

I don't need "n.d." for any entries.  It is fine if it is disabled altogether.

If you want to get rid of all "no dates", you can remove \literal{nodate} from \DeclareLabeldate.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book {dated,
title   = {Dated Work},
date    = {1972},
}
@book {undated,
title       = {Undated Work},
keywords    = {nodate},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Citation of dated item.\footcite{dated}
Citation of undated item.\footcite{undated}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Thanks!  Very helpful.
